# How to format a number to 2 digits in mule4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

I have tried followings;

- `vars.counter as Number {format:'00'}`
- `vars.counter as Number {format:'##'}`
- `vars.counter as String {format:'00'}`
- `vars.counter as String {format:'##'}`

None of the above making `1 to 01`

How can i do this in mule4?

Comment: vars.msgseq as String{format:"00"} is working (using double quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers (integers, floating point) don't have format DataWeave, like in many other languages. You have to convert to a `String` with the desired pattern. I tried the following combinations:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
[
1 as String {format:'##'},
1 as String {format:'00'},
1 as String {format:'#0'}
// , 1 as String {format:'0#'} ERROR!
]
```

Output:

```
[
  "1",
  "01",
  "1"
]
```

Only the all zeros combination gives the desired result.